# static template member variable has internal linkage but is not defined

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, linkage

Yes, I know, there is a question with almost the same title, but it refers to a different situation (giving the same clang error message). In my case, I have a `.cpp` file with a big anonymous namespace (containing implementation details). In that namespace is a traits class template with a static data member, which I need to access from outside the anonymous namespace. Let me flesh this out a bit:

```
file.hpp

namespace bar {
  template<typename A>
  struct foo
  {
    static_assert(is_same<A,float>::value || is_same<A,double>::value, "");
    static void set_static_var(A const&x);
    // ...
  };
}
```

and

```
file.cpp

namespace {
  template<typename A>
  struct foo_traits
  {
    // lots of static code supporting the implementation of bar::foo<>
    static A datum;
  };
  template<> float  foo_traits<float>::datum;   // no change if this is in global namespace
  template<> double foo_traits<double>::datum;
  template struct foo_traits<float>;
  template struct foo_traits<double>;
}

namespace bar {
  template<typename A>
  void foo<A>::set_static_var(A const&x)
  {
    foo_traits<A>::datum = x;
  }
  template struct foo<double>;     // error only appears if these lines are present.
  template struct foo<float>;      // but without these lines, the whole file is void.
}
```

and I get the said error on the variables `foo_traits<>::datum` (and later linkage failure). **Note added in edit** I use `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` (version 3.3), which produced *only* a warning, but (as I've said) in my real application that warning is backed up by a linkage failure (exactly the said symbols are missing). No compiler warnings with gcc, though. Perhaps this is a clang bug? **end note**

What is the correct way to define those variables? Note that declaring them outside the anonymouns namespace won't compile. Note also that, AFAIK, the same construct with an ordinary non-template just works.

**Note** I'm not asking on how to circumvent this problem (that I can think of myself), but how this is correctly done.

Comment: [This (correct) program now compiles without error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4ac6c92c900c18d "Live code at Coliru").

Comment: @Casey Sorry, I forgot the most important lines, namely the template instantinations in `file.cpp`. The error is only exposed if these are added. So, the program is **not correct** after all.

Comment: [Still fine.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a862ab893459b6f)

Comment: @Casey **Compilation without warning does not imply correctness**. I get only a *warning* (with `clang++` v3.3, no warning with `gcc` v4.9), but (in my real application) a subsequent linking failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct solution is simply:

```
namespace {
  template<typename A>
  struct foo_traits
  {
    // lots of static code supporting the implementation of bar::foo<>
    static A datum;
  };
  template<typename A> A foo_traits<A>::datum;
}
```

---

The problem with your code, AFAICT, is that

```
float foo_traits<float>::datum;
```

refers to a specialization for `foo_traits` which does not exist. (the `template<>` in your code is also not allowed, Clang gives an error for it as well).

See [this **live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0172ba6e97457c14).

Comment: @Walter I don't know exactly what the problem in your case is since you haven't shown a SSCCE which actually produces the problem (which is also what Casey is wondering about). I was just showing what I think the correct solution is and what usually works for me (and what also seems to work for your program now IIUC). :)

Comment: Daniel, the code above is a SSCCE in the sense that `clang++ -std=c++11` will issue a warning (but not gcc 4.9).

Comment: @Walter Updated the answer with what I think explains the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a declaration of an explicit specialization of a static data member is a definition only if it includes an initializer, and a declaration otherwise. C++11 14.7.3/13:

> An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template is a definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it is a declaration. [ Note: The definition of a static data member of a template that requires default initialization must use a *braced-init-list*:
>
> ```
> template<> X Q<int>::x; // declaration
> template<> X Q<int>::x (); // error: declares a function
> template<> X Q<int>::x { }; // definition
> ```
>
> —end note ]

[Clang correctly compiles program if you provide initializers for the specializations](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/833b18b6492c397d):

```
template<> float  foo_traits<float>::datum = 0;
template<> double foo_traits<double>::datum = 0;
```

I was erroneous in my belief that the original program was correct, apparently [gcc incorrectly treats the declarations as definitions even when they lack initializers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a862ab893459b6f).

Comment: +1 That also explains why my fix worked: It's not a specialization. Now the puzzle is complete (at least in my head ;)

Comment: @DanielFrey Yeah, all it required was for me to be repeatedly wrong and argue with poor Walter.

Comment: Hmm, initializing would give "non-const static data member must be initialized out of line".